# How to launch one service each time

Tags: angular

I don't know how to explain my problem but in general I want to send 4 api service ofc when I try to send it on the same moment it bring to me an ERROR so I've tried to add each service on the subscribe of the other (Service execute only when the other service bring the data) like that:

```
this._alertSerivce.ChangeFuelStolenAlarm(data).subscribe(stolenfuelValueData=>{
      if(stolenfuelValueData != null){
        this.AlertList.push({Alertkey: stolenfuelValueData['key'],Iscomplete: false});
      }
      this._alertSerivce.ChangeFuelFuelLvlPercentforFillingAlarm(data1).subscribe(fuelDepassementValueData=>{
        if(fuelDepassementValueData != null){
          this.AlertList.push({Alertkey: fuelDepassementValueData['key'],Iscomplete: false});
        }
        this._alertSerivce.ChangeHighFuelConsumptionAlarm(data2).subscribe(fuelConsumptionValueData=>{
          if(fuelConsumptionValueData != null){
            this.AlertList.push({Alertkey: fuelConsumptionValueData['key'],Iscomplete: false});
          }
          this.AlertCounter = this.CommandDisplayList.length;
        },error => {
          console.info(error);
        });
      },
      error => {
        console.info(error);
      });
    },
    error => {
      console.info(error);
    });
```

ok this is a solution! but there are two problem here:

1- when a service (the top one for exemple) didn't launche for any reason the others will never execute, and it is a real problem here.

2- in same cases I have to test first on the first service and second if that option is avalable on that product, So if not I will never use those services soo the third one will never execute also.

This is the first service call (for exemple):

```
ChangeFuelStolenAlarm(Equipment,enable,fuelPercentThreshold){
    let dataStruct = {
      SessionId: localStorage.getItem('SessionId'),   
      Equipment: Equipment,
      Enable : enable,
      FuelPercentThreshold: fuelPercentThreshold
    }
    return this.http.post(`${this.CommandeURL1}/TryToChangeFuelStolenDetectionAlarm`, JSON.stringify(dataStruct), this.httpOptions);
  }
```

I have tried something like adding one param on `ChangeFuelStolenAlarm(data, available)` and use someting like:

```
ChangeFuelStolenAlarm(data, available){
    let dataStruct = {
      SessionId: localStorage.getItem('SessionId'),   
      Equipment: data
    }
if(available){
    return this.http.post(`${this.CommandeURL1}/TryToChangeFuelStolenDetectionAlarm`, JSON.stringify(dataStruct), this.httpOptions);
    }else{
      return null
    }
  }
```

to solve the second problem but I find an error if `available == false`:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null

Comment: Why do you get an error when you try to send them all at once? I think you have a lot of options, you could use forkjoin to make all the requests at once and get an object with each response, but you can only use that if the requests are independent from each other.
If all you want to do is chain them in a cleaner way, you can just use switchMap, that way you would only have one single subscribe, although with switchMap you would still have the problem of the second one not running if the first one fails and so on.

Comment: "Why do you get an error when you try to send them all at once?" cause one of service can pass on server port at the same moment soo I can't get the response of the others